# On the error term of Legendre sieve

Tags: sieve-theory

the Legendre sieve method gives us an upper bound $S$ for the numbers that are not relatively prime to $P_{z}$ up to $x$ where $P_{z}$ is the product of prime number less than z

$S=x\prod_{p<z}(1-\frac{1}{p})+O(2^{\pi (z)})$

I don't understand why the error term is $2^{\pi (z)}$ can someone explain where it came from ?

Comment: How many terms have been changed from $\bigl\lfloor \frac{x}{d}\bigr\rfloor$ to $\frac{x}{d}$ in order to obtain the main term $x\prod_{p < z}(1 - \frac{1}{p})$?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer  i don't understand

Comment: Have you seen the formula for the exact number of $n \leqslant x$ that are coprime to $P_z$?

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer yes I read the proof but I don't understand why the error term is $2^{z}$. Can you explain

Comment: The exact number is $$B_z(x) = \sum_{d \mid P_z} \mu(d)\biggl\lfloor \frac{x}{d}\biggr\rfloor\,,$$ where $\mu$ is the Möbius function. The sum has precisely $2^{\pi(z)}$ terms. Writing $\lfloor y\rfloor = y - \lbrace y\rbrace$, we obtain $$B_z(x) = x\prod_{p \leqslant z}\biggl(1 - \frac{1}{p}\biggr) - \sum_{d \mid P_z} \mu(d)\biggl\lbrace \frac{x}{d}\biggr\rbrace\,.$$ That last sum is the error term. It contains $2^{\pi(z)}$ terms, each of which is smaller than $1$ in absolute value. Hence the error is bounded by $2^{\pi(z)}$.

Comment: Well. I just saw that you used a strict inequality, $p < z$. Then the occurrences of $\pi(z)$ should be replaced with $\pi(\lceil z\rceil - 1) \leqslant \pi(z)$. No big difference, only more inconvenient typography.

Comment: But why you say that there is a $2^{(\pi (z))}$ terms

Comment: Because $P_z$ has that many divisors, it is the product of $\pi(z)$ (or $\pi(\lceil z\rceil - 1)$ for the strict inequality) primes.

Comment: But you choose 2 and not 3 or another number

Comment: I didn't choose, it comes out naturally from the divisor function. Do you know the formula for that?

Comment: Can you explain more

Comment: See [e.g. here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756767/understanding-proof-of-tau-n-k-11k-21-dotsk-r1-and-for-sigma) for the divisor function. In $P_z$, all exponents are $1$, so $\tau(P_z) = (1+1)^{r}$, where $r$ is the number of primes dividing $P_z$.